# Laravel - Running 'npm install' show me unmet dependency - Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, npm

I am currently working on a project in laravel and planning to use elexir to manage my front-end stuffs. I run 'npm install' and warning shows me "npm WARN unmet dependency". What should I do to? Is there a platform issue with this since I am using Windows 8?

Answer (score -1):

Elexir or Elixir? Check the next Link for install [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#windows)

Comment: OP is referring to Laravel's Elixir not the one referred to in your link.